# Angular 14 HttpClient POST not calling

Tags: angular

We are trying to port old Angular 5.x code to Angular 14.
We have the following in app.module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ThemeComponent,
    OnlineStatusComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule,
    LayoutModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ThemeRoutingModule,
    AuthModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ToastModule,
    ResetPasswordModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: API_URL, useValue: environment.apiURL },
    { provide: PSE_URL, useValue: environment.pseURL }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

There were custom interceptors used but are removed currently for testing purposes because of the httpClient.post issue.

HttpClientModule is imported in AppModule and nowhere else.

In auth.service we are making a post request

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient,
        private utilService: UtilService) {
    }

login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
        this.clearSessions();
        let body = { 'username': btoa(username), 'password': btoa(password), 'grant_type': 'password' };

        console.log('login body: ', body);

        let url = serverpath + '/oauth/token';
        return this.http.post<any>(url, body)
        .pipe(
            tap(
                {
                    next: (data) => console.log(data),
                    error: (error) => console.log( error)
                }
                ),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        )

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        console.log(error);
        if (error.status === 0) {
          // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
          console.error('An error occurred:', error.error);
        } else {
          // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
          // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong.
          console.error(
            `Backend returned code ${error.status}, body was: `, error.error);
        }
        // Return an observable with a user-facing error message.
        return throwError(() => new Error('Something bad happened; please try again later.'));
      }
```

In auth.component we are calling the service method

```
signin() {
            this.loading = true;
            console.log('login');
            this._authService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password).subscribe(
                (res) => 
                console.log("login: ", res)
            );
}
```

Problem:

When making the post request the control enters tap, then catchError and exits. But no call is made. Nothing is seen in Network tab of Chrome's DevTools. Console.log in handleError() method is not printed.

What could be going wrong here?

I tried removing the interceptor, removed HttpClientModule declaration in another module and made sure there is only one declaration in AppModule.

Edit: Added constructor of service

Edit 2: To clarify: No calls are made. Chrome DevTools-Network does not show any request.

Comment: Can you show the constructor of the service ? Also, you should remove the `CommonModule`, since it is a child of `BrowserModule`. Never import both. Import `BrowserModule` in the AppModule, and the `CommonModule` in any other component.

Comment: @Random Constructor added in question. After removing CommonModule from AppModule should it be added anywhere else?

Comment: Why do you care about the `error` while using `tap` ? let the catchError handle it and see what the error is since you are mentioning you have a console log ready in there... leave it as `tap((res) => console.log(res)), catchError(...)`

Comment: @Andres2142 Already tried that. Control steps on tap, then catchError and exits. Callback method is not stepped into. And hence console.log in that method not printed.

Comment: Are you saying that you are not getting any of your console.logs to fire?  Can you show what your console looks like after calling login?

Comment: @JakeSmith Console is blank. Nothing is printed. Not the response in tap, not from handleError() method

Comment: Are you certain that the login method is even being called then?  Can you put a console.log above where you subscribe to the login call?  If you don't have anything in the console, I don't think your login call is even happening at all.  When you say tap and catchError get hit, I bet you are hitting breakpoints on when those operators are declared, not executed

Comment: What's the logic implemented for `handleError` function ? also, since you are catching the error while `pipe`ing, after you subscribe. remove the complete and error cycles, just leave it as .`subscribe((res) => console.log(res))`

Comment: @JakeSmith Login method is called. Added breakpoints and hence I know where the program control steps into. Also I have console.log in login method which gets printed.

Comment: `catchError` needs to return an observable if you didn't know... Post the logic for `handleError`

Comment: @Nikitha it would probably help to add all that to your question then.  We need to see what you see in order to help.  I don't see any console.log in your login method...

Comment: @JakeSmith Thank you. Added that console.log line in login method

Comment: @Andres2142 handleError() posted

Comment: @Andres2142 Changed the complete and error cycles after subscribing as you suggested. Could you please elaborate on how to return an observable in catchError since throwError is already called in handleError()?
Also changed the pipe as you suggested. Now it has only the (res) and catchError cycles. Still URL not called.

Comment: temporarily, leave the `handleError` function and change the logic for catchError into this: `catchError((error) => { console.log('Error: ', error); return of(error) })`, where `of` is from `rxjs`. Do that and see if the console log triggers, if it doesn't then, the catchError is not triggered, there is no error happening

Comment: @Andres2142 Changed catchError as per your comment. Control steps over pipe. Does not step into it. As you said no error happens. But why won't the post request fire?

Comment: who is making this call in your component ? `this._authService.login(...)` Are you sure is actually making that call?

Comment: @Andres2142 signIn() method in auth.component calls this service. Whole method is added in code. console.log before calling service method in this method is fired. console.log in the subscriber is not firing. Added breakpoints in this method and control gets handed from this method to service method.